# Regular expression for repeating text in test string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace some code into another with regular expressions. I'm using Java but I think it's not relevant for the question

```
String testString = "sb.Append(\"first string to append(1) \");  sb.Append(\"second string to append(2)\");";
Pattern appendPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\w+)\\.Append\\((.*)\\);");
Matcher appendMatcher = appendPattern.matcher(testString);
System.out.println(appendMatcher.replaceAll("[$1 appendString: $2];"));
```

my expected result is:

```
[sb appendString: "first string to append(1) "];  [sb appendString: "second string to append(2)"];
```

what I got is:

```
[sb appendString "first string to append(1) ");  sb.Append("second string to append(2)"];
```

it's something `.*` has precedence over `\\)` when deciding where match ends.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: @hwnd sorry, was my typo. Now is correct. Feel free to repost your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greedy will consume as much as possible. Follow `.*` with `?` for a [*non-greedy*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) match.

```
\\s*(\\w+)\\.Append\\((.*?)\\);
```

<kbd>[Working demo](http://ideone.com/yi8EUw)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
\s*(\w+)\.Append\((.*?)\);
```

make it lazy along with the global modifier

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/vV0tN6